# Custom caret metric for "precision at k" by groups

Tags: r, r-caret

What is the proper way to create a custom metric function to use in `caret::train` that contains an argument and can summarize subsets of the training data?

Imagine we have credit score and loan data and would like to train a model to predict the top lending prospects within different categories of loans (home mortgage, car loan, student loan, etc.)  We have a limited amount of money and want to diversify our portfolio, so we want to identify a handful of low-risk loans to make in each category.

As an example, we can use the `GermanLoans` data from the `caret` package.  In this training data, each loan is classified as either "Good" or "Bad".  After rearranging some columns, we have the column `Purpose` that identifies the type of loan requested.

```
## Load packages
library(data.table); library(caret); library(xgboost); library(Metrics)

## Load data and convert dependent variable (Class) to factor
data(GermanCredit)
setDT(GermanCredit, keep.rownames=TRUE)
GermanCredit[, `:=`(rn=as.numeric(rn), Class=factor(Class, levels=c("Good", "Bad")))]

## Now we need to collapse a few columns...
##  - Columns containing purpose for getting loan
colsPurpose <- names(GermanCredit)[names(GermanCredit) %like% "Purpose."]

##  - Replace purpose columns with a single factor column
GermanCredit[, Purpose:=melt(GermanCredit, id.var="rn", measure.vars=colsPurpose)[
  value==1][order(rn), factor(sub("Purpose.", "", variable))]]

##  - Drop purpose columns
GermanCredit[, colsPurpose:=NULL, with=FALSE]
```

Now we need to create the custom metric function.  Something like [precision at k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Precision_at_K) (where `k` is the number of loans we'd like to make in each category) averaged over groups seems appropriate, but I am open to suggestions.  In any case, the function should look something like this:

```
twoClassGroup <- function (data, lev=NULL, model=NULL, k, ...) {
  if(length(levels(data$obs)) > 2)
    stop(paste("Your outcome has", length(levels(data$obs)),
               "levels. The twoClassGroup() function isn't appropriate."))
  if (!all(levels(data$pred) == levels(data$obs)))
    stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")

  [subset the data, probably using data$rowIndex]

  [calculate the metrics, based on data$pred and data$obs]

  [return a named vector of metrics]
}
```

Finally, we can train the model.

```
## Train a model (just an example; may or may not be appropriate for this problem)
creditModel <- train(
  Class ~ . - Purpose, data=GermanCredit, method="xgbTree", 
  trControl=trainControl(
    method="cv", number=6, returnResamp="none", summaryFunction=twoClassGroup,
    classProbs=TRUE, allowParallel=TRUE, verboseIter=TRUE),
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(
    nrounds=500, max_depth=6, eta=0.02, gamma=0, colsample_bytree=1, min_child_weight=6),
  metric="someCustomMetric", preProc=c("center", "scale"))

## Add predictions
GermanCredit[, `:=`(pred=predict(creditModel, GermanCredit, type="raw"),
                    prob=predict(creditModel, GermanCredit, type="prob")[[levels(creditModel)[1]]])]
```

**Questions**

- How do I pass the value of k to `twoClassGroup` from the `train` call?  Adding it within the main function arguments doesn't work, nor does adding it within `trControl` or `tuneGrid`.
- How do I subset the data within `twoClassGroup` in order to calculate the model precision for the top k values within each value of `Purpose`?  The `data` object within the `twoClassGroup` function is not the same as the one passed to the original `train` function.

Answer (score 1):

This attempt mostly works, but I'm hoping someone can share a better method.  Rather than passing `dt` and `k` arguments from `train`, they're "hardcoded" in `twoClassGroup`.  Also, the value from `Metrics::mapk` seems very low, although the resulting model does appear to pick the best loan prospects.

```
library(Metrics)

twoClassGroup <- function (data, lev=NULL, model=NULL, dt=GermanCredit, k=10) {
  if(length(levels(data$obs)) > 2)
    stop(paste("Your outcome has", length(levels(data$obs)),
               "levels. The twoClassGroup() function isn't appropriate."))
  if (!all(levels(data$pred) == levels(data$obs)))
    stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")

  data <- data.table(data, group=dt[data$rowIndex, Purpose])

  ## You can ignore these extra metrics...
  ## <-----
  sens <- sensitivity(data$pred, data$obs, positive=lev[1])
  spec <- specificity(data$pred, data$obs, positive=lev[1])
  precision <- posPredValue(data$pred, data$obs)
  recall <- sens

  Fbeta <- function(precision, recall, beta=1) {
    val <- (1+beta^2)*(precision*recall)/(precision*beta^2 + recall)
    if(is.nan(val)) val <- 0
    return(val)
  }
  F0.5 <- Fbeta(precision, recall, beta=0.5)
  F1 <- Fbeta(precision, recall, beta=1)
  F2 <- Fbeta(precision, recall, beta=2)

  ## ----->
  ## This is the important one...
  mapk <- data[, .(obs=list(obs), pred=list(pred)), by=group][, mapk(k, obs, pred)]

  return(c(sensitivity=sens, specificity=spec, F0.5=F0.5, F1=F1, F2=F2, mapk=mapk))
}
```

In the `train` call from the original post, the value of `metric` would be "mapk" rather than "someCustomMetric".